# How to Use the Olson Time Zone Database in PHP?

Tags: php

In particular, I want to write a PHP (-MySQL) script that would find current local date and time for a particular city in the world. It must respect DST changes. For starters, I would like to find current local date and time for all of the capitals in the world. Unfortunately, I can't figure out how to use the Oslon database to accomplish the task. Can someone help me out?

Comment: Olson database? What about [PHP's timezone functions](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetimezone.php)?

Comment: Indeed, the PHP timezone functions use the Olson database - http://devzone.zend.com/article/1457-Zend-Weekly-Summaries-Issue-256

Answer (score 0):

About year ago I was messing with TimeZones in PHP but never got into it seriously. However, I wrote some code and live demo + download are available [here](http://miselkomerc.rs/sho/php/timezones/?cou=GBR) (<300K).

*Screenshot*

[image]

And YES, it observes DST rules.

Comment: This link is now dead.

Comment: @Jason, thanx for notice. download and livedemo links are updated. I had to shut down some domains recently and probably there are a few more dead links here on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: Use PECL's [timezonedb](https://pecl.php.net/package/timezonedb) and built-in `DateTimeZone`. See [Upgrading Olson tz database natively implemented in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8771316/19905) if you want *really* newest timezone updates.

---

1. PHP's built-in timezone database used in the [`DateTimeZone` class](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetimezone.php) is based on Olson's. Might be old release though, which is sensitive for the ever-changing timezone info.
2. Official PHP's way of using the latest timezone data is installing and upgrading PECL's [`timezonedb`](https://pecl.php.net/package/timezonedb):

   ```
   pecl upgrade timezonedb
   ```

   This package is generally updated to the latest release of IANA's (read Olson's) timezone database, which should be good enough for most cases.
3. If you want to live on the bleeding edge of the timezone database, i.e. want to see timezone updates which are not yet included in the official release of the Olson timezone database, you can use sources like current maintainer's github (https://github.com/eggert/tz) for the latest timezone data. For example, as of February 2017, Mongolia's cancelling DST in 2017 is not included in the latest release (`2016j`), but it is included in the github link above.

   But to use that in PHP you will need to recompile `timezonedb` extension. See [Upgrading Olson tz database natively implemented in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8771316/19905) and https://github.com/derickr/timelib for the way to recompile/update PECL's timezonedb from the bleeding edge data (maybe even including your own custom patches). It includes the code to generate `timezonedb.h` which is then used to compile the latest data into the `timezonedb` PECL package.